# How to determine what versions of pypi modules go together?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

For reasons of backward compatibility for an old **wxPython**, I needed to rollback my installed version of the **altgraph** module to 0.7.

When I do so, my installed version of module **modulegraph** is complaining that **altgraph** is not recent enough:

```
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 854, in resolve
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (altgraph 0.7.0 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/altgraph-0.7.0-py2.6.egg), Requirement.parse('altgraph>=0.12'), set(['modulegraph']))
```

Since I know for sure that **altgraph** must remain version 0.7 (and therefore that it is **modulegraph** that I need to roll back), how do I determine what version of **modulegraph** I need to roll back to, without guessing?

I guess this is a general question about how to determine about how to line up module revisions.

Comment: Either the author will have documented it or you'll have to use the tried and true method of just trying different versions until you find one that works

Comment: This is the sort of problem [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) was made for.

Comment: @jwodder How, precisely?